# How to get message of alert dialog?

Tags: c#-4.0, dotnetbrowser

How to capture message of alert dialog using dotnetbrowser ? I have tried to capture message using CustomDialogHandler.customDialogueParams_OnAlert, but still not getting any message.

Answer (score 0):

The following article demonstrates how to catch and customize the JavaScript Alert dialog by registering custom `DialogHandler` implementation:  https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000109867-winforms-customizing-javascript-dialogs